# Azure Function not throwing terminating errors with Stop ErrorAction in Push-OutputBinding

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm trying to build a simple try-catch statement like the following, but that catch block never gets executed

```bsh
try {
  Push-OutputBinding -ErrorAction Stop -Name outputQueueItem -Value $Object
} 
catch {
  Write-Error "Catching Error"
  # code to catch the error
}
```

The problem is that the azure function is not throwing the expected error as terminating besides the fact I had the `ErrorAction Stop` parameter. Therefore the `catch` code never gets executed.

Output Log:

```
[8/18/2020 9:42:11 PM] INFORMATION: 00:00:09.9511800
[8/18/2020 9:42:11 PM] Executed 'Functions.Monitor' (Failed, Id=6bf398bd-de2b-460f-a44b-db9838feff3f)
[8/18/2020 9:42:11 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.Monitor. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Messages cannot be larger than 65536 bytes.
```

The error was expected, however, the catch code block never got executed.

Runtime Information:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2630 Commit hash: beec61496e1c5de8aa4ba38d1884f7b48233a7ab)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13901.0
```

I have also tried to change the variable `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` but it didn't work either.

Comment: If `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` then `Write-Error "Catching Error"` is going to abort the execution of the `catch` block, avoid throwing errors from inside it (at least until you're done with your error handling)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Btw your booking-com career link is dead ;)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the contribution, I didn't knew that one. However, on the sample code shared above that should not happen as the ErrorAction Stop it's only at the command level and $ErrorActionPreference is continue and doesn't print the error inside the catch

Comment: @ErickGuillen Correct, it shouldn't have an impact with `Continue` as the preference variable - but I'm suspecting maybe the Azure Function script runner might be reacting to the error emitted and aborting execution? It's speculation, but maybe worth a try?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just gave it a try. Even with the `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` it continues the execution after the generating error code in the try function and never triggering the catch.
I think maybe something odd it's going on with the Azure Function Runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can't catch this exception because it happens *after* the script is completed. The `Push-OutputBinding` command does not directly write data to Azure Storage. Instead, it just stores it in an internal data structure, and the actual writing to Azure Storage happens after the function completes.

See also: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/284

The workaround is to change your script to write to Azure Storage directly instead of invoking `Push-OutputBinding`, so you can implement your own error handling.